# The limit of a sequence $u_{n+1}=\exp(u_n)+u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Please help me to find the limit of this sequence :

$ u_0=-2017\;$ and $\; u_{n+1}  =e^{u_n}+u_n $

I don't know if the limit exist or not.

Comment: HINT: $$u_{n+1}-u_n = e^{u_n}>0$$ implies that the sequence is strictly increasing. Thus the limit necessarily exists (possibly $+ \infty$). Now, $$u_{n+1}-u_0= \sum_{k=0}^n e^{u_k} > \sum_{k=0}^n e^{u_0} = u_0 \cdot (n+1) \to \infty$$

Comment: Hmm... raises the question of whether it's "converges to infinity" or "diverges to infinity".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the limit $l$ exists, $l=e^l+l$ implies $e^l=0$ impossible.